# Linking directly from a site's main page to a post (via answered/modified link) makes the post appear red in color

Tags: bug, design, posts

Normally when you click the modified/answered link next to a question in a feed, it takes you to the post that got the update, highlighting it in orange for a moment, and then fading back to transparent.  I encountered a weird issue today where the post turned red, then orange, then transparent:

I'm having a hard time explaining it, but I clicked [this link](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/1851/pal-nes-in-usa-50hz-vs-60hz/?lastactivity):

[image: Link]

And then this happened:

[image: Red Post]

[image: Orange Post]

[image: Normal Post]

What happened?  Did I summon cthulhu?  Is this a Winterbash thing?

Comment: No, that's an animation. Are you using a remote desktop to browse?

Comment: Nope, Chrome 55 on Mac OS X El Capitan.  I guess the animation was just slow for some reason?

Comment: Yeah, I guess so.

Comment: That's what it looks like. Perhaps you had something CPU intensive running at the same time?

Comment: @Oded possibly loading other browser tabs.  Do you think it's worth it to keep this post open or should I just delete it?

Comment: Something very rare - and not easily reproducible. I don't see that as something we can realistically fix...